# Is storing references to DOM objects in global closures very inefficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a given global IIFE closure

```
var foo = function(){
   var x;

   function doStuffToX(){
      ...
   }

   return { doStuff: doStuffToX }
}();
```

where x would be a reference to a DOM element.

Which of the below methods would be more efficient, given that there are 30+ of these DOM references, and `foo.doStuff()` would be rarely-sometimes invoked? Note that this would be a one-page app and therefore memory would not be cleared out.

1. Storing a reference to `#x` in `foo.x`

```
$(function(){
   foo.init();
   foo.doStuff();
});

var foo = function(){
   var x;

   function init(){
      x = $('#x');
   }

   function doStuffToX(){
      ...
      x.modifyDom();
      ...
   }

   return { init: init, doStuff: doStuffToX }
}();
```

2. Querying for `#x` in `doStuff()`s closure

```
$(function(){
   foo.doStuff();
});

var foo = function(){

   function doStuffToX(){
      ...
      var x = $('#x');
      x.modifyDom();
      ...
   }

   return { doStuff: doStuffToX }
}();
```

Comment: 1 is more efficient in speed in the cases where the function is called, 2 is more efficient in memory.  Rather than worrying too much about such micro-optimisations, just write your code, then if you perceive a performance issue, start profiling the code to see where it needs to be improved.

Comment: Another thing to consider, on top of performance and memory usage, is the risk of an error. If you initiate selectors prior to executing your code, you create a risk that you will be working with stale references - i.e. you select an element, you later modify html that includes that element, which in reality creates a brand new element with the same properties, but your old reference now links to non-existing element and not what's on the page anymore. Be careful when caching selectors, it's not always worth it.